# Can't make div overflow scrollable using Tailwind

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I need #projects div to take up rest of the space that exist and be scrollable when there is too much items

Note: I have 10 elements*, and rest just not showing because i have overflow-hidden in body element
[image]

Shoud be somemthing like this (it is using h-96, but i need all of the space)
[image]

```
  <div class="grid flex-1 grid-cols-12">
    <div class="col-span-12 flex flex-col bg-gray-800 text-gray-50 md:p-8 xl:col-span-8">
      <div class="flex items-center justify-between p-5 md:mb-8 md:p-0">
        <span class="text-[16px] font-semibold tracking-wide md:text-[14px]">All projects</span>
        <MenuDropdown />
      </div>
      <div id="projects" class="flex-1 overflow-y-auto">
        <ProjectItem v-for="project in projects" :key="project.id" :project="project" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you'd like the projects container to take up the rest of the viewport height. To do this, consider applying `height: 100vh` via the `h-screen` class to the vertical flex layout parent. This means there is a limit to how much the projects container can grow in height, meaning any overflow would be scrollable:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      projects: Array(100).fill().map((_, i) => ({ id: i })),
    };
  },
});

app
  .component('menudropdown', { template: '<div>MenuDropdown</div>' })
  .component('projectitem', {
    props: ['project'],
    template: '<div>Project {{ project.id }}</div>',
  })
  .mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.3.4/vue.global.prod.min.js" integrity="sha512-39BSQXI5q1XlvVhLfFRidKG8KM6Tr6VS/XSnNo6N/A0ZXexHCeoUI/s+ulujQy3UREjoLNrMnFat8VI0mMugWA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="grid flex-1 grid-cols-12">
    <div class="col-span-12 flex flex-col bg-gray-800 text-gray-50 h-screen md:p-8 xl:col-span-8">
      <div class="flex items-center justify-between p-5 md:mb-8 md:p-0">
        <span class="text-[16px] font-semibold tracking-wide md:text-[14px]">All projects</span>
        <MenuDropdown />
      </div>
      <div id="projects" class="flex-1 overflow-y-auto">
        <ProjectItem v-for="project in projects" :key="project.id" :project="project" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is it is part of the layout [image](https://tailwindui.com/img/component-images/dark-project-app-screenshot.png)

Comment: You could look at applying the solution to your layout. Otherwise, consider asking a question with code more relevant to your problem – I would expect any solutions not to be helpful to you if you ask a question that omits crucial information.